# How to get specific part of line in specific format in directories?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, directory, ofstream

```
------------------------------------------------
          Artikli vo magacin za obleka          
------------------------------------------------
Vo magacinot ima vkupno 5 artikli
------------------------------------------------
Sifra : 3
Opis : opis2
Edinecna cena : 212
Vlezna kolicina : 2
Izlezna kolicina : 0
Danocna stapka : 0
Iznos : 424
Datum na vlez : 20324
------------------------------------------------
Sifra : 3
Opis : 54
Edinecna cena : 123
Vlezna kolicina : 12
Izlezna kolicina : 0
Danocna stapka : 0
Iznos : 1476
Datum na vlez : 120915
------------------------------------------------
Sifra : 3
Opis : opsi2
Edinecna cena : 12
Vlezna kolicina : 324
Izlezna kolicina : 0
Danocna stapka : 0
Iznos : 3888
Datum na vlez : 570509
------------------------------------------------
Sifra : 2
Opis : vopi
Edinecna cena : 2
Vlezna kolicina : 2
Izlezna kolicina : 0
Danocna stapka : 0
Iznos : 4
Datum na vlez : 951230
------------------------------------------------
Sifra : 1
Opis : opis1
Edinecna cena : 2
Vlezna kolicina : 2
Izlezna kolicina : 0
Danocna stapka : 0
Iznos : 4
Datum na vlez : 101
------------------------------------------------
```

The above is a file called "directory.dat" and I want to know how can I take off the integer of a specific line containing a specific text? For example, if I want to make a sum of all the lines with "Edinecna cena", how can I specifically get all integers from those lines only?

Comment: You need to pull in all the lines, parse the lines and search them for the first non character. Find the integers that way, it looks like all ":" is before all the integers as well so you could use that as a delimiter.

Comment: `awk '/Edinecna cena/ {sum+=$NF;print $NF} END {print sum}'`?

Comment: @twalberg What does that mean?

Comment: @Matt2234 Can you give me a hint what should I use to parse? And also, will the little space before the integer cause problems?

Comment: It means "print the last field of every line that matches "Edinecna cena", and print the sum of all those fields at the end...

Comment: Oh.. I don't understand that language. Sorry about that. Do you mind if you give me a hint how it's done though? I will read the directory line by line and check if a line starts with "Edinecna cena", but then how do I grab the integer value?

Comment: @user2699298 He is using "awk" to parse it, it's a like grep and can be used to work with text. That is a good way to go about it and you can modify it to use with use files of the same structure.

Comment: Also, cs.dvc.edu/HowTo_Cparse.html – Matt2234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file line-by-line (the proper approach without `eof()` is suggested by **0x499602D2**):

```
ifstream dir("directory.dat");
string line;
while(getline(dir, line)){
    //(process the line)
}
```

Check whether your line (`string priceLn = "Edinecna cena : ";`) matches to the beginning of the line, and extract the price:

```
// process the line:
if(line.find(priceLn)==0){
    price = stoi(line.substr(priceLn.size()));
}
```

**PS:** `strncmp()` can incur in smaller overhead while reading the file. We can rewrite the if statement like this:

```
if(line.size() >= priceLn.size() && 
   strncmp(line.c_str(), priceLn.c_str(), priceLn.size()) == 0) {...}
```

Comment: How exactly do I "extract" the price only?

Comment: @user2699298 it's being extracted in the line `price = stoi(line.substr(priceLn.size()));` Or you can accumulate all the prices with `+=` operator.

Comment: `while (!eof())` is fundamentally wrong. Change it to `while (getline(dir, line))`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `std::getline()` returns `istream&`. What's wrong with `eof()`?

Comment: `getline` *does* return `istream`, but `operator bool()` (`operator void*` pre-C++11) checks `!fail()`. The loop should only exit when the stream fails to extract.

Comment: Your code has the disadvantage of checking the state of the stream *before* the extraction is performed, when it should be done the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex library and create a regular expression to parse the file line by line for you.

/(Edinecna cena) : (\d+)/ will work as a solution to the example you asked for. The integer will be contained in the second group and you can replace the item in the first group with whatever you are searching for.

Comment: I've never used Regex before in C++, but as I can see it seems that the library `#include <regex>` is only available in C++11, which I can't use for this project.

Comment: If so, then a simple strncmp should suffice. Call it on each line with n being the length of the string you are looking for, then find ':' in the line, +2 to its index, and convert the string starting there to an integer. This will work just as well, it's just not as clean as a regex.

Comment: Do you mind if you give a very little snippet of how strncmp would be used in my example? Just the arguments inside the strncmp is enough.

Comment: `if(strncmp("Edinecna cena", inLine, strlen("Edinecna cena")) == 0) {
/* String matches */
}`

Comment: What exactly is inLine here? The contents of that line we're comparing to?

Comment: Yes, the result of getline();